# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B"' when trying to assign possible values to a string

Tags: html, angular, typescript, types, event-handling

I have two values from a select option. For better readability, I defined the only two possible values that the user can choose, but I'm getting a type error with this approach:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    SERVER
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
        <mat-option value="A">Server A</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="B">Server B</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</div>
```

**TS**:

```js
const SERVERS = {
  SERVER_A: "A",
  SERVER_B: "B",
}

private origin: typeof SERVERS.SERVER_A | typeof SERVERS.SERVER_B = SERVERS.SERVER_A;

onChange(e) {
    this.server = e.value;
    this.setServer(this.server); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B"'.
}

setServer(server: "A" | "B"): void { }
```

Am I doing it the wrong way or this is not possible?

Comment: You likely want `const Servers = { /*...*/ } as const;`

Comment: Can you show the `setServer` method?

Comment: It's defined as setServer(server: "A" | "B"): void {  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can create a `type` which is *valueof* `SERVERS`.

```js
const SERVERS = {
  SERVER_A: 'A',
  SERVER_B: 'B',
} as const;

type SERVERS_VALUE = typeof SERVERS[keyof typeof SERVERS];
```

And declare `server` with `SERVERS_VALUE` type.

```js
server: SERVERS_VALUE;
```

This method can be amended to

```
setServer(server: SERVERS_VALUE) { }
```

Instead of:

```js
setServer(server: 'A' | 'B') { }
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wtn24l?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

### Reference

[Objects vs Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)